# How to Map AltGr + any key to shortcut in Openbox/Lubuntu file lubuntu-rc.xml

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, openbox, lubuntu

I have a highly customised lubuntu-rc.xml file; all key combinations that I can use for command shortcuts are mapped, so I need to utilise more keys so I can have more shortcuts.

I would like have AltGr keyboard shortcuts as are suggested by the following (xev utility reveals that AltGr is key 108 which is also called ISO_Level3_Shift).

```
<keybind key="ISO_Level3_Shift-q">
   <action name="Execute"><command>script1.sh</command></action>
</keybind>

<keybind key="ISO_Level3_Shift-j">
   <action name="Execute"><command>script2.sh</command></action>
</keybind>
```

In other words use AltGr in the same way the Windows key is used.

However even after inserting the above into **lubuntu-rc.xml** and running
 `sudo openbox --reconfigure` I find that AltGr + q produces an @ symbol.

How do I take control of AltGr mapping for this purpose?

*ps In the same way I would also like to take advantage of the blue coloured Fn key (xev utility reveals this has keycode 151 and name XF86WakeUp) however I am also unable to take control of this key using key maps such as XF86WakeUp-q or XF86WakeUp-j*

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AltGr is "mod5"

for example to launch Terminal by means of 'AltGr + t'

```
    <keybind key="mod5-t">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>lxsession-default terminal</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

you probably have already found a solution, but it is worth to answer anyway 'cause could be useful to someone googling around...

Comment: Thanks very much @guest. I had `mod5` as `ISO_Level3_Shift` which is what the utility XEV shows. How did you find `mod5`?

Comment: For me didn't worked **mod5**, but worked **Alt_R** in LXDE, Ubuntu 20.04